# Are Canadian provinces and territories administrative divisions, and what is an "adminstrative division"?

Tags: united-states, canada, constitutional-law

In its current version, Wikipedia's article titled "Quebec" tells us that

> Quebec is Canada's largest province by area and its second-largest administrative division; only the territory of Nunavut is larger.

Thus the ten provinces and three territories are here being considered "adminstrative divisions".

Maybe a year or so ago I was appalled to see [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/U.S._state) telling us that states in the United States are administrative divisions of the country, and I changed it.

In the U.S. there were formerly "organized incorporated territories" (and maybe the District of Columbia could still be considered one of those?). These I take to have been administrative divisions of the country. Congress passed an "organic act" for each such territory that said the government in this territory shall be organized in thus-and-such manner. During the existence of such a territory, if it was decided to change the term served by the governor from two years to fours year, or make some other change, the change was enacted by Congress, not by the voters in the territory. The constitution of a state, by contrast, is drafted by politicians in that state and submitted for the approval of the voters, and any changes are made by popular vote; there is no involvement of Congress or anything at the federal level. Thus states are not administrative divisions of the federal government. Counties, in those states where they exist (or parishes in Louisiana or boroughs in Alaska), are administrative divisions of the state.

Thus it seems appropriate that in the U.S., states get "admitted" by Congress whereas territories get "organized" by Congress. However, in Canada, if I'm not mistaken, both provinces and territories get "admitted".

So

- Is this understanding of the concept of "administrative division" right?
- Is the article about Quebec right?

Comment: An administrative division is just a subdivision of an area were each division has some sort of government/administration.

Comment: @mkennedy : So maybe I should have phrased the question thus: What is an administrative division _OF_ some larger entity? My idea was that organized incorporated territories within the U.S. were divisions _OF_ the federal government, having been organized by Congress, whereas states were not organized by Congress but by persons within the state.

Comment: Well, yes, a territory had to meet certain requirements set by the federal government to become a state including an act by congress and once it achieves statehood, a state has certain rights and privileges deriving from the federal government as well as rights and privileges deriving from itself.

Comment: @mkennedy : Perhaps we should note that the idea of a territory becoming a state oversimplifies things. In many cases a _part_ of a territory became a state, and no consent of the territorial legislature was needed for that. In three or four cases a part of a state became a state, and I say "three or four" because of disputes about one of them. Kentucky was a part of Virginia and became a separate state. Maine was a part of Massachusetts and became a separate state. There are disputes about whether West Virginia's admission as a separate state from Virginia was....

Comment: ....constitutional, but no one (?) disputes that it was made a separate state. The fourth case was Vermont. New York's claim to Vermont was disputed, and there never was a time when New York generally governed Vermont, but Vermont was not admitted until the consent of New York's legislature removed an impediment.

Comment: Ohio was the easternmost part of the Northwest Territory, and it became a state while the rest of the territory became the Indiana Territory. When the easternmost part of that became the state of Indiana, the rest became an organized territory. When the easternmost part of the territory of Wisconsin became the state of Wisconsin, most of the territory became the territory of Iowa. When the southernmost part of that territory became the state of Iowa, most of it became the territory of Minnesota. When most of that became the state of Minnesota, the rest became unorganized territory.

Comment: Much later, in 1889, the territory of Dakota become two states.

Comment: So thinking of what happened as a territory becoming a state on numerous occasions is probably misleading.

Comment: In each of the four cases when part of a state or something that was claimed to be part of a state was admitted as a new state, either the consent of the legislature of the claimant state occurred first, or (in the case of West Virginia) was at least asserted to have occurred first. But I doubt that any consent of a territorial legislature was ever granted for part of the territory to become a state.

Answer (score 3):

"Administrative division" is a sub-national area that exists for the purpose of administration - it is context dependent and is independent of the area having self-governance  or legal certainty or continuity. That is, they may be large or small, geographically contiguous or not, permanent or temporary, democratic or non-democratic, self-governing or externally administered etc.

The states and territories of the [US](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Political_divisions_of_the_United_States) can be considered administrative divisions. Counties and their equivalents are administrative divisions. Cites, towns, villages and other types of municipalities are also administrative divisions.

Australia has states and territories. Some states have counties. Some states have counties divided into parishes. All states have local governments (cities, municipalities and shires) whose boundaries do not relate to counties or parishes. Some governments form larger administrative divisions for certain purposes (e.g. [WSROC](https://www.wsroc.com.au/) - Western Sydney Regional Organisation of Councils, the [Murray-Darling Basin Authority](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murray-Darling_Basin_Authority)). All of these are administrative divisions.

Comment: Can states in the U.S. be considered to have been defined for the purpose of administration?

Comment: @MichaelHardy Regardless of the reason for their formation, they are nevertheless also divisions that are used for administration (thus "administrative divisions"). The term is descriptive and doesn't imply anything about formation, or specific powers, or sovereignty.